# Regex match partial word with nothing before but spaces allowed

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match some class names in a string that start with *row-* but it can't allow characters before the match, except space.

I've used `/row-/g` and `/\s?row-/g` and word boundaries but the problem arises when the user could possibly use a class name with foo-borrow-bar where the *row-* in borrow returns a match or `some-row-class`.

My example string of class names i'm testing against:

`row-some-class foobar hello-world-row-class foo-borrow-bar row-it-is`

I only want to match `row-some-class` and `row-it-is`

Comment: can you use a caret (`^`) to specify the beginning of a string? like this: `/(?:^|\s)row-/` or maybe a lookbehind `/(?<!\w)row-/`

Comment: I don't think there is look-behind in JS Regex.

Comment: @AnthonyStringer While I know what the caret's use is, I'm not sure how it helps the match process in my case. With or without, I'm doing a global look up for all instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
(:?^|\s)row-
```

You can either have "row-" at start of the line or in front of whitespace in order for it to be valid.

```
(:? # Non-capturing group
    ^|\s # Matches tart of string/line or whitespace
)row-
```

Comment: This was a perfect solution to my problem and even ignored the case where a user could have used row in among another name such as some-row-class. Thanks!

Comment: this will mach xyz-row-ab class also. which doesn't start with row

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar Not according to my test https://regex101.com/r/jN3aN8/1#javascript

Comment: Oh, seems I pasted wrong regex in my answer. Now I see that my current regex matches `hello-world-row-class` too...

Comment: @Slayther please check my link above. It seems to work fine even when i added hello-world-row-class

Comment: Your link works fine because you removed the dash. I did so too in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can surround the pattern using word boundaries, `\b`:

```
\b ?row-\b
```

Also note that, `\s` is not just space, its actually

```
[ \t\n\r\f\v]
```

so unless you are sure about the input, better be explicit to avoid unexpected results.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT0rM9/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.match()` with `RegExp` `/row-\w+-\w+/(?=\s|$)/g` to match `row-` followed by word followed by `-` followed by word if followed by space character or end of input

```js
console.log(
  "row-some-class foobar hello-world-row foo-borrow-bar row-it-is"
  .match(/row-\w+-\w+(?=\s|$)/g)
)
```